# How to set a timezone to an existing timestamp without reinterpreting it?

Tags: go, timezone

I'm parsing timestamps sent by users. The timestamps are local to a location but the source string doesn't specify it. Server-side I'm looking up the timezone of the location and need to shift the time into that timezone, without changing its display value.

I know I can do this to give me the equivalent time at a different location:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    myTime := time.Now()
    fmt.Println(myTime.Format(time.RFC3339))
    
    loc, err := time.LoadLocation("America/New_York")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    
    fmt.Println(myTime.In(loc).Format(time.RFC3339))
}
```

This just prints:

```
2009-11-10T23:00:00Z
2009-11-10T18:00:00-05:00
```

Which isn't what I want.

I'm trying to find a way of setting the timezone to e.g. `America/New_York`, so I should get e.g. `2009-11-10T23:00:00-05:00`, which is the original local time, but with the New York offset applied.

How can I do this in Go?

Comment: I believe https://pkg.go.dev/time#ParseInLocation is the way to go, if you have a `string` to work with. Your description and your code make conflicting statements in what is the input to your problem.

Comment: is this what you wanted?
`t := time.Date(myTime.Year(), myTime.Month(), myTime.Day(), myTIme.Hour(), myTime.Minute(), myTime.Second(), 0, loc)`

Comment: ParseInLocation won't work for me it seems. The time is already parsed while deserialising from JSON, so I guess I'll have to do it manually like @EminLaletovic suggests :-/

Comment: @jbrown, what do you mean by «The time is already parsed while deserialising from JSON»? JSON does not have any type to represent time so `encoding/json` has no way to automatically interpret any value in a JSON document as representing a timestamp.

Comment: what do you mean by "*shift the time into that timezone*"? if the timestamp you parse already represents the time in some time zone, you don't need to shift anything, you net to **set** the time zone.

Comment: [time.Time.UnmarshalJSON decodes only RFC3339](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time.UnmarshalJSON), and therefore the original string must include a UTC offset. Is your intention to ignore this offset and pretend it's something else?

Comment: @Peter yes, exactly. I need to reinterpret it as the offset of the location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The confusion comes from the fact that the API that intuitively comes to mind [`In`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time.In) simply interprets the same point in time as if it were in a different time zone. So when you print it, the display isn't what you want.

To set the time zone to a timestamp while keeping the same display value you can simply construct the new timestamp with `time.Date` with the same values as the original timestamp and the new location:

```
t := time.Date(myTime.Year(), myTime.Month(), myTime.Day(), myTime.Hour(), myTime.Minute(), myTime.Second(), myTime.Nanosecond(), loc)
// 2009-11-10T23:00:00-05:00 in the playground
```

---

Another option is to set the time instance to the new time zone, then use [`Zone()`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time.Zone) to get the offset, and then subtract its value in seconds from the localized time.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    myTime := time.Now()
    fmt.Println(myTime.Format(time.RFC3339))
    
    loc, err := time.LoadLocation("America/New_York")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    locTime := myTime.In(loc)
    _, zoneOffset := locTime.Zone()
    
    inZoneTime := locTime.Add(-time.Duration(zoneOffset) * time.Second)

    // handle DST transitions
    if inZoneTime.IsDST() {
        inZoneTime = inZoneTime.Add(1*time.Hour)
    }
    
    fmt.Println(inZoneTime.Format(time.RFC3339))
    // 2009-11-10T23:00:00-05:00
}
```

To test the DST transition in your local machine today (assuming you are in a non-DST country, as I am) you can change the location to a place where DST is active, e.g. `Australia/Canberra`.

With an input of `time.Now()` without DST into `Australia/Canberra`, the above program prints the following:

```
2021-11-12T13:27:33+01:00
is DST: true
2021-11-12T13:27:33+11:00
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/5qy2tOcIMwn