# Is it possible to manually assign time zone and information regarding whether the time falls under DST, in golang?

Tags: go, time

I am receiving timestamp objects in the form of `time.Time` along with a string that denotes the associated location string i.e. `America/Phoenix`. I check whether or not the time being provided falls under DST or not? If it is I would like to modify the time with the appropriate region, offset and a string denoting whether the timezone falls under Daylight savings or not.

I have a function timeMapper, which works like so.

```
var tzm = map[string]timezoneInfo{
    "Mountain Time (US & Canada)": {"America/Phoenix", "MST", "MDT"},
    "Atlantic Time (Canada)":      {"America/Toronto", "AST", "ADT"},
    "Pacific Time (US & Canada)":  {"America/Los_Angeles", "PST", "PDT"},
    "Indiana (East)":              {"America/Indianapolis", "EST", "EDT"},
    "Eastern Time (US & Canada)":  {"America/New_York", "EST", "EDT"},
    "Saskatchewan":                {"America/Regina", "CST", "CDT"},
    "Alaska":                      {"America/Anchorage", "AKST", "AKDT"},
    "Central Time (US & Canada)":  {"America/Chicago", "CST", "CDT"},
}

func timeMapper(t time.Time, timezone string) (time.Time, string) {
    timezoneInfo, _ := tzm[tz]

    zoneID := ""
    zoneLocation := timezoneInfo.name
    if IsDaylightSavings(t) {
        zoneID = timezoneInfo.dst
    } else {
        zoneID = timezoneInfo.std
    }

    loc, _ := time.LoadLocation(zoneLocation)

    return t.In(loc), zoneID
}
```

The function timeMapper would take something like this

`2018-10-29 14:00:00 +0000 UTC, "America/New_York"`

And return something like

`2018-10-29 10:00:00 -0400 EDT`

Comment: I've added code that basically describes what I am trying to do and how

Comment: you can check if a certain time instance is in DST with [Time#IsDST](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time.IsDST). Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: This is part of the problem, I already implemented a function that does just this, checks whether the time isDST or not. I want to manually convert the time to the appropriate timezone and apply the DST offset for that timezone

Comment: I see. Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/q/69941303 this probably isn’t a direct answer to your issue, but hopefully gives you some ideas

Comment: Your solution in the link you've shared is exactly what I am trying to do the only difference is that, in the output I would like  an addition to the timestamp like `EDT` or `EST` denoting whether or not the time was in DST or not

Comment: By "output" you mean the string format? Then you should be able to do that by adding `MST` to the format string, e.g. `"2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 MST"` https://go.dev/play/p/H743NWWDZqn

Comment: Yes, the string format needs to include this information, but to be more specific, could this extra information `MST` or `MDT` be modified? Like if isDST returns true we put use `2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 MDT` else `2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 MST`.

Your solution does the job, but the values MST and MDT aren't correct, even if the timestamp should be following daylight saving time.


Correction: Your solution works but not for some timezones, but not for `America/Phoenix`. `MST` is always returned even if it's DST or not.

Comment: I found a solution in [this Stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54552101/how-to-construct-time-time-with-timezone-offset)

Thank you for all your help it is really appreciated, need to get better at putting issues I am faced with on paper.