# Dealing with Timezones and Unix Timestamp in Golang

Tags: go, unix-timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

Given the following code:

https://go.dev/play/p/moLVHXIc4ba

It shows the next result:

```
now: 2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC m=+0.000000001 | inLoc: 2009-11-10 18:00:00 -0500 -05unix | now: 1257894000 | inLoc: 1257894000
```

I don't get why when I call .Unix() to the date evaluated in Lima location, I get the same timestamp that original date in GMT.

I expect to get the timestamp corresponding to the original timestamp in GMT with 5 hours less as Lima has UTC -5.

Comment: The Unix seconds of a timestamp do not depend on the location. They're just the number of seconds from Jan 1st 1970 UTC. [`Time.Unix`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time.Unix)

Comment: @blackgreen ok, and then how can I get the timestamp with 5 hours less to pass to frontend? I don't want frontend to handle the logic of show time depending on location

Comment: *I don't want frontend to handle the logic of show time depending on location* — that's a bad idea, the locale of a timestamp is a matter or presentation. What if your frontend is used by someone who's located in Australia?

Comment: @blackgreen well then my backend response has timestamp already "translated" to Australia time location. That means that the client in australia and in any part of the world reads the timestamp as it's UTC, because the server moves the timestamp in UTC x hours depending on time location. I can't give that responsability to frontend because the timezones are configured by organization.

Comment: then have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69941303/how-to-set-a-timezone-to-an-existing-timestamp-without-reinterpreting-it/69942521#69942521), but be aware that it's full of pitfalls (e.g. DST transitions, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

> I expect to get the timestamp corresponding to the original timestamp in GMT [UTC] with 5 hours less as Lima has UTC -5.
>
> how can I get the timestamp with 5 hours less to pass to frontend?

---

You appear to be asking for this `inLocTimestamp` function. Five hours is 18,000 (5 * 60 * 60) seconds.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func inLocTimestamp(inLoc time.Time) int64 {
    _, offset := inLoc.Zone()
    ts := inLoc.Add(time.Duration(offset) * time.Second)
    return ts.Unix()
}

func inLocTimestampMilli(inLoc time.Time) int64 {
    _, offset := inLoc.Zone()
    ts := inLoc.Add(time.Duration(offset) * time.Second)
    return ts.UnixMilli()
}

func main() {
    loc, _ := time.LoadLocation("America/Lima")
    now := time.Now().Round(0)
    inLoc := now.In(loc)
    fmt.Printf("time       | now: %v | inLoc: %v\n", now, inLoc)
    fmt.Printf("unix       | now: %v | inLoc: %v\n", now.Unix(), inLoc.Unix())
    fmt.Printf("timestamp  | now: %v | inLoc: %v\n", now.Unix(), inLocTimestamp(inLoc))
    fmt.Printf("difference | inLoc: timestamp - unix = %v\n", inLocTimestamp(inLoc)-inLoc.Unix())
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/IyzA4qZLLuS

```
time       | now: 2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC | inLoc: 2009-11-10 18:00:00 -0500 -05
unix       | now: 1257894000 | inLoc: 1257894000
timestamp  | now: 1257894000 | inLoc: 1257876000
difference | inLoc: timestamp - unix = -18000
```